# How to center the logo in OptimizePress editor?

Tags: css, wordpress

I created a header using the "Layout Settings" menu and added a logo.

I won't have navigation at the moment (but planning to add it in the future), so I used the "Logo With Alongside Navigation" option.

Now I want to center the logo, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using "Banner/Header with navigation below" instead of "Logo With Alongside Navigation"?